# Does the MongoDB stats() function return bits or bytes?

Tags: mongodb

When using MongoDB's .stats() function to determine document size, are the values returned in bits or bytes?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Bytes of course. Unless you pass in a scale as optional argument.

Answer (score 137):

Running the [collStats](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/collStats+Command) command - db.collection.stats() - returns all sizes in bytes, e.g.

```
> db.foo.stats()
{
    "size" : 715578011834,  // total size (bytes)
    "avgObjSize" : 2862,    // average size (bytes)
}
```

However, if you want the results in another unit then you can also pass in a `scale` argument.

For example, to get the results in KB:

```
> db.foo.stats(1024)
{
    "size" : 698806652,  // total size (KB)
    "avgObjSize" : 2,    // average size (KB)
}
```

Or for MB:

```
> db.foo.stats(1024 * 1024)
{
    "size" : 682428,    // total size (MB)
    "avgObjSize" : 0,   // average size (MB)
}
```

Comment: You've ~682GB stored in MongoDB?

Comment: what if I have a decimal? ` "avgObjSize" : 5378.817689030945,`

Comment: The avgObjSize is not affected by the scale parameter (1024) it always returns Bytes. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/

Comment: I was returned `storageSize` amongst others... didn't see `size`. Using mongodb v2.6.12

Comment: @Hartator I use GridAdapter for files, so anyone can get 1TB of images, :P

Answer (score 20):

```
db.stats()                in Bytes
db.stats(1024)            in KB
db.stats(1024*1024)       in MB
db.stats(1024*1024*1024)  in GB
```